# How do I log into another user's OS from my network OS using terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, permission

To preface this: I'm sure this has been asked but I don't know exactly what I'm searching for or what terms to use, so I am going to ask here by explaining my situation.

I am logged onto a network OS on a host machine (10.9) and I need to view and edit files on the Macintosh HD that is on this actual host machine. The reason why I need to do this is the user's machine is kernel panicking because of a Trend Micro kext in his OS. Whenever I try to go into the user library on Macintosh HD to delete the plists as well, I get "Permission Denied" even when using sudo. I **do** have the username and password of the user that I'm trying to edit so my question is: How do I log in, through terminal, as that user to edit things inside that users Library folder?

Hopefully this makes sense -- if not let me know and I can try to clarify further.

Edit: To further explain myself and why I'm going about it this way is simply because I'm curious. If I boot into safe mode it works just fine as it doesn't load the kext. I'm just wondering how this would be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say that the user you are trying to become is 'newuser', we'll use the 'su' command (switch user) like so as follows...

Start the terminal and enter:

```
sudo su - newuser
```

When prompted enter YOUR password (not newuser's password)

When done you should be logged in to a terminal window as that user.